# vim clickable url in pdf

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using macvim  for a ruby tutorials book that will be produced directly with vim as a PDF (using the macvim print/make pdf function but the principle should be the same for any PDF generated from Vim). Unfortunately in the text part of the tutorial book there seems be no easy way to make a url clickable in the pdf.

What is the best solution to have clickable URLs in .pdf files generated from vim ?
thanks in advance !

Comment: I use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to make PDFs from vim. You write them in markdown format and then generate them.

Comment: Hi Conner that is probably the best/easiest approach but I was wondering if there are other solutions. I did manage to get the syntax highlight on the PDF exactly how I wanted it with a plugin that allows me to separate normal book text from code so it would be a pity to go back the markdown route (not talking about the time factor!) so if there is any way to do it without pandoc let me know!

Comment: It seems to work for me. I just typed "This is a test: http://google.com" into MacVim 7.3.604 and then hit ⌘P and the link is clickable in the PDF. What version are you on? Are you preceding your links with `http://`?

Comment: I am using macvim build snapshot 64 (the latest) vim 7.3 and I can confirm that both This is a test: http://www.google.com or this is a test: google.com etc. does not work to make the link clickable in the PDF after ⌘P but are you using a tag or something ?

Comment: Nope I just typed `This is a test: http://google.com`. Will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really after producing a "book", I would reconsider your approach. After all, you cannot get around certain Vim limitations like a single, fixed-width font, and detailed control of page breaks, table of contents, etc. will be difficult to achieve.

If you just like the syntax highlighting of (Ruby) code, you can use Vim's `:TOhtml` command to get a faithful rendition of a Vim buffer in HTML, which I suppose can then be included in your publishing master.

To make links clickable in PDF, you'd probably have to "decompile" the binary format into PostScript, then do a text search for URLs and modify the PostScript code to include a link, then recompile to PDF. I haven't found a (command-line) tool that does this, but I guess some of the (GUI, often expensive) PDF editors allow you to do that.

Comment: I agree; I would really reconsider going with pandoc and markdown or at least some format that you can preserve and convert to other formats.

Comment: Hello Ingo, Do you know any simple way in markdown to produce colored, ruby syntax? If you do I really think this question is solved :)

Comment: @devnull: I don't think Markdown includes code highlighting, nor is it it's purpose. I suggest using Markdown (or similar) for the book's text, and render the code separately, then combine everything as a final step. One code highlighter I know is http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html